# CIMaskedVariableBlur filter on iOS 8 / 32-bit does not work

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, cifilter

The following code uses the CIMaskedVariableBlur filter on iOS8. The code works fine on 64-bit devices, but fails on 32-bit devices - it just returns a black image.

Any idea?

```
    /*  filteredImage:adjustVariableBlurWithImage
     *
     *  blur the image with a mask (iOS8 only)
     */

- (CGImageRef) filteredImage:(UIImage*)image adjustVariableBlurWithImage:(UIImage*)maskImage {
        CGImageRef cgImage = nil;
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CIImage* ciImage   = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];
        CIImage* ciMask    = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[maskImage CGImage]];

        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMaskedVariableBlur"];
        [filter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [filter setValue:ciMask  forKey:@"inputMask"];
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

        CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        CGRect extent = [result extent];
        cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];

        return(cgImage); 
}
```

This image shoes the results on 64-bit (left) and 32-bit (right):

[image]

Comment: I am running into the same problem, you find a solution or workaround?